# Not Receiving Push Notifications iOS in Kill State React native

Tags: react-native, apple-push-notifications, react-native-push-notification

I am using **@react-native-community/push-notification-ios: "^1.10.1"**
When the app is in background I am receiving notifications perfectly but when app is killed by OS the notifications are not received in iOS.

Also when app is reopened, I received notifications that are sent in Killed State.

React Native Version: "0.69.1"

```
PushNotification.configure({
    // (optional) Called when Token is generated (iOS and Android)
    onRegister: function (token) {
        console.log("PUSH NOTIFICATION TOKEN:", token.token, token.os);
 
    },

    // (required) Called when a remote is received or opened, or local notification is opened
    onNotification: function (notification) {

        if (Platform.OS == 'ios') {

            PushNotificationIOS.addNotificationRequest({
                id: notification.data.msgId,

                title:notification.data.title,
                body: notification.data.body,
                userInfo: { jobId: "123" },
                isSilent: false,
            });

        }
```

Comment: @Suulola I implemented firebase push Notifications worked fine on both devices